# Filter objects queryset by foreign key django

Tags: django, python-2.7, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

I got this code

```
class Author:
    data1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book:
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

How can I filter authors that have at least one reference from book?
I'am on django 1.6
Python 2.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Auther.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1) # a book instance
author =  book.author_set.all()   #all  Author from book
author.filter(data1='xxx') #filter 

for i in author:
    print i. data1    # i is Author instance
```